Tailwind Grid Only Stacks
Coming from a bootstrap background and trying to learn Tailwind.
In bootstrap we can do
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-4">1 Column</div>
   <div class="col-4">2 Column</div>
   <div class="col-4">3 Column</div>
</div>

And we'd get a traditional table like display with the 3 columns spanning across the screen.
But I've been trying the below Tailwind code and it only stacks the columns on top of each other.
<div class="w-full mx-auto">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-1">
        <div class="col-span-4">Column</div>
        <div class="col-span-4">Column</div>
        <div class="col-span-4">Column</div>
    </div>
</div>

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The code itself seems to work as you desire as per this Tailwind Play which would lead me to suggest it is some other configuration issue. Consider checking the content file globs sufficiently cover the file that the code is in.
